# How is that Chaos Galand can't defeat Gawain, but Pellegarde could?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Supposedly no Magic Knight can defeat a Ten Commandment, but Pellegarde who is a Magic Knight could defeat Gawain, but Ten Commandment Galand with increased power by Chaos couldnt.

How is that Chaos Galand can't defeat Gawain, but Pellegarde could?